# Can't upgrade from Ubuntu 19.10 to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, 19.10

I actually upgraded from 18.04 to 19.10 recently(just 2 weeks before) as it said that there is no new version. So I changed the "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" settings to "For any new version" and upgraded me to 19.10. Now I want to upgrade to 20.04. But if I give the
"Upgrade" button, it does nothing. I think that my PC is slow or my PC isn't compatible with this version.

**My PC's Specs and model:** ***HP Pavilion G6 1a52-nr, Intel Core i3 (i think gen 3 model), 3 GB ram.***

Comment: Thanks for that. I will try that.

Comment: Actually it says there is an upgrade to 20.04 but clicking that button dosen't do anything.

Comment: You may not need to make the change to *old-releases* yet (my ISPs mirror still has *eoan*), as there is no *date* after EOL that release are dropped, only that it's **after EOL**.   I'd try update from terminal first, as the messages are a huge clue, and easier to find on terminal (I think anyway).  The best documentation for update is always the release notes for the release you want to bump to, ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes  (see the *Upgrading from* section)